# how to get Cell Signal Strength in Lte without getAllCellInfo in android

Tags: android-activity

I am using bellow code to get Signal Strength in Lte.

```
for (final CellInfo info : tm.getAllCellInfo()) {

  if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
     final CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
         lte.getDbm();
  }

}
```

But `getAllCellInfo` in returning `NULL`. So what is way to initialize `CellSignalStrengthLte` without calling `tm.getAllCellInfo`?
my API version is 17.